# Arduino CPP object reference in assignment

Tags: c++, arduino, variable-assignment, assignment-operator, copy-assignment

I have the following Ardruino CPP code.  This code works fine:

```
while (rtc.now().second() != 0) delay(50);
curDateTime = rtc.now();
```

I wanted to move the assignment into the loop so that I'm capturing the time I'm actually testing.  I thought I could assess the result of the assignment as shown below, but while the following compiles, it apparently throws an exception.

```
while ((curDateTime = rtc.now()).second() != 0) delay(50);
```

I'm using the first example, so it is working, but I really would like to understand what I did wrong with the second example.

I kept the example super short in the hope that my error would be obviously and easy to explain.  If not, I will just dig in a little more on my side.

Many Thanks!!

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Add this line to barebones sketch with all the necessary imports to get it to run.

Comment: Just a guess - you're calling.second() without knowing that you have an object from rtc.now()

Comment: The second example looks terribly... wrong. Delay inside while(_condition_) ?...

Comment: Are you sure the exception comes from that bit of the code?  Morgoth is right, we need a small, complete example.  We need the context to understand the problem.